# Get more than One value and display it

Tags: java

I am checking 'n' number of servers every minute, if any servers are down a mail is triggered to an user with the server name that is down. The issue I am facing is that if more than one server is down I am getting only one server name that is down. How to get the name of all servers that are down.

```
   obj = dataAccess.getServers();  //getting the status and links of all servers
   MailServer sender = new MailServer(From,Password);           
   List<String> downserver = new ArrayList();
   for (Map<String, String> objs : obj) { //Iterating for each server
                serverstatus = objs.get("status");
                if (serverstatus.equals("DOWN")) {
                    servername = objs.get("name");
                    statusserver=objs.get("status");
                }

  downserver.add(servername);
  if(!(servername.equals(null))){
        sender.sendMail("Server Status",downserver.get(i),From,To)
   }
```

Comment: Convert the `List` to a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). Call `filter` to select the servers that are down, and `map` to convert the servers to server names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without checking for reasonability of your code or trying to improve anything, your code should look a little more like the following to (at least) come close to what you are trying:

```
servers = dataAccess.getServers();
MailServer sender = new MailServer(From,Password);

List<String> downservers = new ArrayList();
for (Map<String, String> server : servers) {
    serverstatus = server.get("status");
    servername = server.get("name");
    if (serverstatus.equals("DOWN") && servername != null) {
        downservers.add(servername);
    }
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep = "";
for (server : downservers) {
    sb.Append(sep).Append(server);
    sep = ", ";
}
sender.sendMail("Server Status", sb.ToString(), From, To);
```

or short with one iteration:

```
MailServer sender = new MailServer(From,Password);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep = "";
for (Map<String, String> server : dataAccess.getServers()) {
    String servername = server.get("name");
    if (server.get("status").equals("DOWN") && servername != null) {
        sb.Append(sep).Append(servername);
        sep = ", ";
    }
}
sender.sendMail("Server Status", sb.ToString(), From, To);
```

Comment: If I try your way, n number of mails are triggered if n number of servers are down. I want to trigger only one mail with all the down server names

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do `null` check on a string, you should not do `servername.equals(null)`, if servername is null, it throws a `NullPointerException`. You can use `if (servername != null)`.

You can also use the variable servername instead of `downserver.get(i)` in sendMail method.

Check if you are getting `NullPointerException` or some other exception.